# Code coverage tools for regexes?

Tags: regex, code-coverage

Are there tools out there to measure code coverage of regexes? A tool that given a regex and a list of input strings, tells you which parts of the regex are exercised, with measures analogous to statement coverage, branch coverage, condition coverage, etc.

I don't care much what language or environment it runs in.

(Update: after some more thought, I was realizing that it's pretty easy to start with a regex and generate various exemplars. There are some tools out there to do this: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/rex/ , http://code.google.com/p/xeger/ ). They don't seem to try to get full coverage, though; they just take random paths through the DFA.)

Comment: You must have some doozies of regexes if this has your attention.  How big are they (length) and what are you doing with them?  ( I have something similar as sets of token descriptions for langauge front ends, so this caught my attention).

Comment: This comes up in the context of a heuristic used on an open-ended set of human-created input documents. It's difficult to feel confident about the implementation in those situations, so I figure anything that can raise my confidence level is worth investigating.

Comment: Re update: you don't want to test your regexes by generating paths through them, from the regexes. That won't demonstrate anything except that one can enumerate the paths through a regex, and I doubt if there's any disagreement about this.

Comment: What I was thinking with that was that if you generate 'enough' exemplars, then verify by hand that each fits your specification, then you have a pretty good list of test inputs to start with. For a suitable definition of 'enough'...

Comment: If you generate your exemplars from the regexes themselves, by definition they will match but that doesn't tell you anything about whether the regexes are useful for your *specified* task.  "Don't test the code, test the requirements"

Comment: ... I build test coverage tools.  I've never seen one for regexes. If you want me to respond on how to build such a thing, I'll do that.

Comment: Right, it's that 'verify by hand' step where you might learn something. And when the regex changes, you might learn something, too. Anyway, not the ideal solution, just a part of an overall solution.

Comment: I'm probably not motivated enough on this particular problem to build something very comprehensive. I spent an hour with http://www.brics.dk/~amoeller/automaton/ and http://jung.sourceforge.net/ and was able to visualize state and edge coverage in a DFA for a slightly complicated regex and test strings, which was fun, but I'll let someone else make a real product out of it. Though my real wish would probably be for a product for XPath coverage (including embedded calls to matches())...

Comment: @Steven: Er, coverage for XPath seems very different than coverage for regexes.   You mean, "coverage for all of XPath including the regexes in matches"?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, so that's a different question that I'll ask later :-). I thought I'd start small.

Comment: Try program "The Regex Coach"

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It's an interesting tool, but doesn't do coverage, specifically, as far as I can see on the site.

Comment: https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex is a more modern implementation that generates all or some "guarantee to match" inputs.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RXPY seems hackable enough to implement what you want :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am also interested in testing Regexes, and measuring the coverage achieved by these Regex tests. I have not found an off the shelf tool yet, but a [research paper](http://people.engr.ncsu.edu/txie/publications/ase09-reggae.pdf) did indirectly measure regex test coverage by first converting the regex to a [Brics Automaton](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/), then from a Brics automaton to an XML representation, and then from that XML representation to a c# implementation of the automaton, using a technique inspired by [Alekseykin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/parser.aspx). It appears that this was an automated process. I got this information directly from one of the paper authors, and he also directed me to the [project site](https://sites.google.com/site/asergrp/projects/reggae). I have not yet tried it, but intend to. Perhaps someone can beat me to it and report on their findings.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/test.html) - It allows you to open a testfile and run it against your regex and show you matches etc. It's pretty cheap considering how useful it is.

Comment: I was going to suggest that too, but for debugging, RegexBuddy gives you a "merely" visual aid (which is perfect for debugging a regex), and since those debug trees can be thousands and thousands of lines long (and do not measure anything except the overall steps necessary to match or fail), I'm not sure that's what he needs. Definitely try it, though.

Comment: It looks like an interesting tool, but yeah, probably not exactly what I meant. I'll come back to it if I don't find any spot-on answers.

Comment: It's probably the sort of tool you want lying around if you're doing anything complex with regexes.